# Any associative, commutative, division algebra is a field. Is the converse true in a sense?

Tags: vector-spaces

Essentially I am wondering about the question in my title. It is easy to show that any associative, commutative, division algebra over a field is a field. I'm wondering if the converse is true. I'm not sure how to argue, as strictly speaking a field is not a vector space (and therefore it cannot be an algebra). Does one simply take a field as a vector space over itself and then show that it's an algebra? Is this just a trivial fact?

Comment: I'm confused. Why isn't that the definition of a field?  And you can't say "algebra" without saying what the ring of scalars is.

Comment: How is a field not a vector space? Isn't it a vector space over itself?

Comment: @Randall Edited, my apologies.

Comment: I see @morrowmh, I guess it's just that huh? It's not strictly speaking a vector space since a vector space is an ordered pair (set of vectors, scalars) whereas a field is not, but I guess as you say there is a natural identification.

Comment: It's just (field elements, field elements).

Comment: Is this an isomorphism between the space of fields and the space of vector spaces where the vectors and scalars are the same, or is this not even the right language to use? @Randall

Comment: Every field $K$ has the structure of a vector space over $K$ where the vectors are just the elements of $K$ and the scalar multiplication is the field mulitplication.  That's it.

Comment: For a statement of the form $A,B,C \Rightarrow D$, what do you mean by "converse"?

Comment: Any field is an algebra over its prime subfield?

Comment: @GEdgar I mean $D \implies A,B,C$.

Comment: Fair enough @Randall , thank you for your help! It seems silly in retrospect, but I guess my confusion hinged/hinges on the word "is". I guess I should be thinking of "is" as "can be seen as".

Comment: ^good point of view.